# MongoDB Group By with limit in each group

Tags: mongodb

For instance I have a collection:

```
{"people_id":"4878", "team_id" : "461", "match_name" : "Bellerín", "position" : "Defender"} 
{"people_id" : "6196", "team_id" : "462", "match_name" : "M. Özil", "position" : "Midfielder"}
{"people_id" : "4878", "team_id" : "463", "match_name" : "Bellerín", "position" : "Defender"}    
{"people_id" : "6196", "team_id" : "464", "match_name" : "M. Özil", "position" : "Midfielder"}
{"people_id" : "15430", "team_id" : "465", "match_name" : "A. Lacazette", "position" : "Forward" }
{"people_id" : "5437", "team_id" : "466", "match_name" : "B. Leno", "position" : "Goalkeeper"}
```

How can I do a query in Mongodb to get total 15 records and maximum 3 from each `team_id`, Also maximum 5 from each `position`

I want to get like this:

```
{"_id": "Defender", "items": [
    {"people_id":"4878", "team_id" : "461", "match_name" : "Bellerín", "position" : "Defender"},
    {"people_id" : "6196", "team_id" : "462", "match_name" : "M. Özil", "position" : "Defender"}
  ]
}
{"_id": "Midfielder", "items": [
    {"people_id":"4870", "team_id" : "465", "match_name" : "Bellerín", "position" : "Midfielder"},
    {"people_id" : "6190", "team_id" : "463", "match_name" : "M. Özil", "position" : "Midfielder"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: 5 positions per team?

Comment: 1 position can have maximum 5 people, and sum of all the people in all the positions must be 15. these 15 people should not be from one team_id, maximum 3 people from a single team_id should be there

Comment: Max 3 person per team. 5 person per position. So query can select 3 persons from team 1 with midfielder pos? Am I correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct